# BATCH (Windows Command Prompt) - FORFILES returning "ERROR: The parameter is incorrect."

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2012-r2, forfiles

I have a very simple batch script that is trying to utilize the `FORFILES` command in command prompt windows on my Windows Server 2012R2 server...

The purpose of this batch file is to look through a bunch of directories (with sub directories) and delete files that are X days old or older.

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

SET "MINDAYSOLD=9"
SET "TARGETPATH=E:\archives"

SET "PADDEDTIME=%TIME: =0%"
SET "DATESTAMP=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%"
SET "LOGFILEPATH=Logs\%~n0-%DATESTAMP%.log"
SET "WORKINGDIR=%~dp0"

CALL :CreateDirectory "%WORKINGDIR%Logs"

ECHO Wiping files that are %MINDAYSOLD% or more days old...
ECHO Target Path: "%TARGETPATH%"
ECHO.

ECHO Searching folder: %TARGETPATH%
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%b IN (
        `forfiles /p "%TARGETPATH%" /S /M *.* /D -%MINDAYSOLD% /C "cmd /C ECHO @path" 2^>nul`
) DO (
        SET "filepath=%%~b"
        SET "filename=%%~nxb"
        ECHO   Found !filepath!
        ECHO   Deleting !filename!
        DEL /F /Q /A "!filepath!"
        REM TIMEOUT /NOBREAK /T 1
        IF EXIST "!filepath!" (
                ECHO   Error deleting file^^!
        ) ELSE (
                ECHO   Success.
        )
)
ECHO   Checking if folder %TARGETPATH% is empty...
SET "filesearch="
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%c IN (
        `DIR /B /A-D "%%~a" 2^>nul`
) DO (
        SET "filesearch=%%c"
)
IF {!filesearch!}=={} (
        ECHO   Folder is empty, deleting folder...
        RD /Q "%TARGETPATH%"
        REM TIMEOUT /NOBREAK /T 1
        IF EXIST "%TARGETPATH%" (
                ECHO   Error deleting folder^^!
        ) ELSE (
                ECHO   Success.
        )
) ELSE (
        ECHO   Folder is NOT empty^^!  Skipping deleting.
)
ECHO.

EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%


REM =================================================================
REM ! FUNCTIONS                                                     !
REM =================================================================

REM == Create directory =============================================
:CreateDirectory
IF NOT EXIST "%~1" (
        MKDIR "%~1"
)
EXIT /B 0
REM =================================================================
```

There are many files in the folder and I'm just trying to get 1 day old files returned.  For some reason the command keeps returning the following...

```
...
ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.
ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.
ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.
ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.
ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.
ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.
ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.
ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.

test
test
...
```

I'm trying to figure out why in the world I'm getting those errors.  Any ideas?

Comment: Just tested your code and I do not get any errors.

Comment: I'm still testing to try to find out why it's happening but it's 100% happening for me.  So far it seems to not have an issue with a smaller amount of files using a path that is deeper ex: `E:\archives\01\02\03\04` instead of `E:\archives`.  Still looking into it though.

Comment: Hm... Windows Server 2012... I believe to remember there was an older version of `forfiles` than on modern Windows systems (from Windows Vista onwards), which was a bit different in terms of syntax... You could try to replace `*.*` by `*`, then you could replace all `/` by `-`...

Comment: @aschipfl I think that it's important for this to be tagged `batch-processing` that you removed.  Otherwise users might think this is commands ran at the command line itself.

Comment: No, that's the tag [tag:batch-file] is for; [tag:batch-processing] is something completely different! please read the related tag info...

Comment: @aschipfl no need to get excited.  It says `Batch-processing refers to programmatic execution with minimum human interaction.`.  Is that not what my batch script is doing?  Maybe something is not clicking with the way you are reading that description and the way I'm reading it.  `programmatic execution` check, `minimum human interaction` check.

Comment: @aschipfl thanks for the tips about older versions of `FORFILES` in Windows.  The syntax for the command does use `/` and not `-` for the switches.  Though I think `-` still might be accepted.  Did not try the `*.*` to `*` trick.  That might have worked.

Comment: Well, most scripts execute with minimum interaction, that's what scripts are for... ;-) Anyway, your question is about a batch-file and there is a specific tag for that; adding the generic tag batch-processing would add no value at all...

Comment: Sorry for the wrong hint concerning `/`/`-`, my mind was fooling me... The `*.*`/`*` issue will not solve your problem, but there is a difference in behaviour: `*.*` would not match files with no extension, but `*` would (opposed to `dir`, for example, where both variants match such files)... And something else: `/D -1` returns files modified yesterday *and earlier* (when I reread your question it sounds like you want files from yesterday only, but I'm not quite sure)...

Comment: Yea I might have given the wrong impression, my `/D -X` variable (like `MINDAYSOLD` in my answer) was meant to delete files that are X days or older.  For example in my answer I use `MINDAYSOLD=9`.  That would mean delete all files that are 9 or more days old.  Thanks!

Comment: Based on your answer below you were not showing us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) within your question.

Comment: @Squashman It is as Minimal as I can make it to be Complete.  I wanted to show my work, so that everything was accounted for and ensure that someone could copy paste the answer, change a few variables at the top and achieve success.  It might not meet the "Minimal" standards but in my experience on SO the answers I find with a little more explanation (on point) help out more to where I can cherry pick what I like.  My answer shows a different way to get all the files in a bunch of sub directories rather then just using `FORFILES`.  Feel free to submit a better answer.

Comment: @Squashman I realized you were talking about my question and not my answer.  My question has been updated and now is more clear to the objective.  I don't think many that try to run this on a small file/folder set will get the same results that I got as I said in another comment.  I think it has to do with the number of files (there are an eminence amount of files) and the depth of the directory structure.  When I split up the `FORFILES` job into many different tasks like in my answer it seems to handle the job with 100% no issues.  Just shared hoping it helps others like it did me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coming up with the following script that fixed my issue.  I replaced the FORFILES with a FOR loop looking through each directory, then used FORFILES in each directory.  This way FORFILES did not have to dig through subfolders.  The following script goes through each folder (including sub folders) and then deletes files and has a lot of verbose information.

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

SET "MINDAYSOLD=9"
SET "TARGETPATH=E:\archives"

SET "PADDEDTIME=%TIME: =0%"
SET "DATESTAMP=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%"
SET "LOGFILEPATH=Logs\%~n0-%DATESTAMP%.log"
SET "WORKINGDIR=%~dp0"

CALL :CreateDirectory "%WORKINGDIR%Logs"

ECHO Wiping files that are %MINDAYSOLD% or more days old...
ECHO Target Path: "%TARGETPATH%"
ECHO.

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a IN (
    `DIR "%TARGETPATH%" /S /B /AD /O:N`
) DO (
    ECHO Searching folder: %%~a
    FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%b IN (
        `forfiles /p "%%~a" /S /M *.* /D -%MINDAYSOLD% /C "cmd /C ECHO @path" 2^>nul`
    ) DO (
        SET "filepath=%%~b"
        SET "filename=%%~nxb"
        ECHO   Found !filepath!
        ECHO   Deleting !filename!
        DEL /F /Q /A "!filepath!"
        REM TIMEOUT /NOBREAK /T 1
        IF EXIST "!filepath!" (
            ECHO   Error deleting file^^!
        ) ELSE (
            ECHO   Success.
        )
    )
    ECHO   Checking if folder %%~a is empty...
    SET "filesearch="
    FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%c IN (
        `DIR /B /A-D "%%~a" 2^>nul`
    ) DO (
        SET "filesearch=%%c"
    )
    IF {!filesearch!}=={} (
        ECHO   Folder is empty, deleting folder...
        RD /Q "%%~a"
        REM TIMEOUT /NOBREAK /T 1
        IF EXIST "%%~a" (
            ECHO   Error deleting folder^^!
        ) ELSE (
            ECHO   Success.
        )
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO   Folder is NOT empty^^!  Skipping deleting.
    )
    ECHO.
)

EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%


REM =================================================================
REM ! FUNCTIONS                                                     !
REM =================================================================

REM == Create directory =============================================
:CreateDirectory
IF NOT EXIST "%~1" (
    MKDIR "%~1"
)
EXIT /B 0
REM =================================================================
```